# Maximum current when shorting BLDC motor phases

Tags: mosfet, motor-controller

I have a motor control application.  To stop the motor in an emergency, the low side MOSFETs are shorted. The BLDC motor itself has a R-phase-phase of 0.12 ohm, a Ls of 100 uH and runs from a +48 VDC supply @ 3000 rpm.

As far as I could figure out with some tests, the peak current when I short the motor phases at specific angular velocities seems to be proportional to the angular velocity (makes absolute sense, since the BEMF constant will mainly be responsible for that.) Further, most of the energy is stored in the kinetic energy of the load and the motor rotor intertia itself, so the peak current should also increase when the motor load increases. The slew rate of the current should be limited by Ls, right?

What I would like to calculate is the actual peak current the MOSFETs could take for 1 ms and 10 ms (gate voltage of 12 V, so fully saturated.) In theory, the motor produces a current of +48 VDC/0.12 ohm = 400 A, but the slow down of the motor is so fast, that this peak current will probably never occur with the loads I'm using. Some no-load measurements lead to a peak current of around 60 A @ 3000 rpm.

The SOA in the datasheet looks like this:
[image]

How can I figure out what MOSFETs can handle for 1 ms and 10 ms? This is only a single pulse (should only occur very rarely.) My Vds when I assume a Rds of 3 mohm and a motor Rs of 0.120 mohm is around 1.18 V (+48 V supplied by the motor at full speed and voltage divider) and so according to the SOA, the MOSFET will not be able anyway to carry more than 150 A for this voltage.  Is this not a problem for the MOSFET?  Should I be more concerned that the motor may be damaged?

[MOSFET datasheet.](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-ISC030N10NM6-DataSheet-v02_00-EN.pdf?fileId=8ac78c8c7bb971ed017bb9a9887300a4)

Comment: I'd be worried about the max length of the current pulse, at the highest stored energy in the system ... e.g. stopping from 3000rpm down a steep hill. If you know the stored energy, how long does it take to dissipate that at I^2*R?

Comment: Hi, the machine will be used in a CNC application, so the only mass comes from the system and the motor itself is able to dissipate the energy.